# parsing XML configuration file using Etree in python

Tags: python, xml, config, lxml, xml.etree

Please help me parse a configuration file of the below prototype using lxml etree. I tried with for event, element with tostring.  Unfortunately I don't need the text, but the XML between

```
<template name> 
   <config>
 </template>
```

for a given attribute.

I started with this code, but get a key error while searching for the attribute since it scans from start

```
config_tree = etree.iterparse(token_template_file)
for event, element in config_tree:

    if element.attrib['name']=="ad auth":
        print ("attrib reached. get XML before child ends")
```

Since I am a newbie to XML and python, I am not sure how to go about it. Here is the config file:

```
<Templates>

  <template name="config1">

    <request>

      <password>pass</password>

      <userName>username</userName>

      <appID>someapp</appID>

    </request>

  </template>

  <template name="config2">

    <request>

      <password>pass1</password>

      <userName>username1</userName>

      <appID>someapp</appID>

    </request>

  </template>

</Templates>
```

Thanks in advance!

Expected Output:

Say the user requests the config2- then the output should look like:

```
   <request>

      <password>pass1</password>

      <userName>username1</userName>

      <appID>someapp</appID>

    </request>
```

(I send this XML using httplib2 to a server for initial authentication)

FINAL CODE:

thanks to FC and Constantnius. Here is the final code:

```
    config_tree = etree.parse(token_template_file)
    for template in config_tree.iterfind("template"):

        if template.get("name") == "config2":
            element = etree.tostring(template.find("request"))

            print (template.get("name"))
            print (element)
```

output:

```
     config2

    <request>

         <password>pass1</password>

          <userName>username1</userName>

          <appID>someapp</appID>

    </request>
```

Comment: I don't get it, what should be the output you expect?

Comment: Hey FC, just added requested output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to iterate over all `template` elements in the XML and parse them with the following code:

```
for template in root.iterfind("template"):
    name = template.get("name")
    request = template.find(requst)
    password = template.findtext("request/password")
    username = ...
    ...
    # Do something with the values
```

Comment: hey, thanks again. I could work on it. have posted the answer along with my question. please check

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `get('name', default='')` instead of `['name']`

To get the text in the tag use `.text`

Comment: hey, the default thingy is helpful, i could handle errors with that. thanks FC