# Read list from text file

Tags: python

I have been experimenting with ways of storing some variables from my python project in a user readable/editable text file. The text file is laid out like this:

```
a = "hello"
b = 123
c = [4,5,6]
```

As you can see, a is meant to be a string, b an integer, and c a list. The code I have so far goes as follows:

```
for line in file:
    name = line.split('=')[0]
    value = line.split('=')[1]
    vars()[name] = value
```

It splits the line at the '=' and sets the first section as the variable name, and the second section as the value for that variable.

However, when the program runs, instead of coming out as an integer and a list, b (123) and c ([4,5,6]) both are saved as strings.

Is there any way that I can convert the strings into their proper types? Or is their a better (but still simple) way of doing what I am trying to do?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `eval`, but there a piles of security risks attached.

Comment: Have a look at [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).  Unlike `eval`, it is safe to use.

Comment: maybe just make a function that says "hey, is this a list?" using stuff like `line.startswith('[')` (or even regexes like a boss)  and then use string manip to sort it out, and eventually int() on the stringed ints to finally convert them...... would be safer than eval/exec, but actually require work

Comment: You would want exec not eval I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
def config_file(filename):
    result = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split('=',1)
            result[line[0]] = ast.literal_eval(line[1].strip())
    return result

print config_file('cfg.txt')
```

You'll probably want more beef in the `for` loop, like ignoring blank lines, removing comments, etc.

Also note that this puts the data in a `dict`, and not into the `vars()` dict. You should [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). If you do want to add your config variables to your namespace, you can still use my function like so:

```
vars().update(config_file('cfg.txt'))
```

Answer (score 4):

**"Or is their a better (but still simple) way of doing what I am trying to do?"**

**Option 1**
One easy and good way is to use a dictionary in a python file just do an import.

**myConfig.py**

```
cfg={'a':"hello", 'b':123, 'c':[4,5,6]}
```

**In your code:**

```
from myConfig import *
print cfg['a']
```

You can also use indvidual variables instead of dictionary and do the same.

**Option 2**

If you don't want a python file you can read any other file and use `exec` to executing the command line by line. Docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

You can use `execfile` but I believe it is discontinued in versoin 3.x Docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

**Option 3**

**You can also use other ways:**

1. Python ConfigParser:     https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html
2. YAML files:  http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation
3. XML files: See this for an example:
       [parsing XML configuration file using Etree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108319/parsing-xml-configuration-file-using-etree-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers below, for simple data structures you can use `json` format and dictionaries or namedtuples:

```
import json
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import namedtuple

json_vars = """{
    'a' : "hello",
    'b' : 123,
    'c' : [4,5,6]
}"""


print json_vars
from_json = literal_eval(json_vars)
# or:
# from_json = json.loads(json_vars)

variables = namedtuple('Vars', from_json.keys())(*from_json.values())

print variables
print variables.a
print variables.b
print variables.c

print variables._asdict()
d = dict(variables._asdict())
print d

print d['a']
print d.items()


as_json_again = json.dumps(d, indent=2)

print as_json_again
```

For more advanced objects, see `pickle` module.